# Fluid dynamics problem related to flow through capillary tube

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

The rate of flow of liquid through a capillary tube of radius $r$ is $v$ when pressure difference across the two ends of the capillary is $p$.

> If pressure is increased by $3p$ and radius is decreased to $r/2$, find the new rate of flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship between pressure drop and flow rate for viscous flow through a tube is $$\Delta p=\eta \left(\frac{4L}{D}\right)\left(\frac{32Q}{\pi D^3}\right)$$ where $\eta$ is the viscosity and $Q$ is the volumetric throughput rate.

If $D$ is halved, then $D^4$ is $1/16$ as high.  So, $4 \times (1/16) = 1/4$.  $Q$ will be $1/4$ as large.

Comment: can you pleasetell where did I went wrong in my answer ?I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You went wrong when you tried to solve it using Bernoulli's equation.  For an inviscid fluid (which Bernoulli's equation describes) the pressure drop in a straight pipe or capillary is zero.

Comment: I did not get it why is the pressure drop zero?. Thanks for the response.

Comment: is it because,. As viscosity is zero no viscous force will be there. And viscous force is the reason for pressure drop in tube.

Comment: Sure. That is the reason.